# Paperless office questions

Tags: forms, paperless

I've been leading my department towards going paperless for a little over a year now and we have figured out some great ways to save space and money while not using dead trees.

Everything is going swimmingly, except for one thing. Digital forms, E-forms, whatever you want to call them. My particular job (IT Auditor) requires a lot of forms to be filled in and we have a bunch of them made by someone else in Infopath, who converted our old paper forms for us. For reasons that would require a chapter here, Infopath is not the right solution for us. I've tried Word forms and they just don't look as professional as Infopath did.

So I'm looking for *another* solution where we can create a digital form that looks professional **with minimal effort and can save the information within the form**.

PDF would be the ideal solution, but I have not found a way to save the information within the form properly. I've looked at a couple of solutions, such as those presented [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29434/how-to-save-fillable-form-data-in-pdfs/), but I just think someone must have thought of a more professional way to achieve this in the current age of paperless offices. Help me out Super Users! I'm willing to pay for the right software, so I want the **best** solution, not necessarily FOSS.

Edit: I have used Word and want a solution other than MS Office. I cannot store forms online, otherwise I'd just create a HTML form on our website and submit the information to a MySQL database, which would be the ideal solution. I am specifically looking for software that allows form creation and can save the form **with the information filled out on it**. I have found something that might work and answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked at [PhantomPDF](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/phantomPDF/) by Foxit, which at first glance seems to do what I am wanting to do: Create a (PDF) form, fill it out and save the form with the information intact.

Alternative software seems to require Adobe LiveCycle Forms Designer to run

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Word](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/) has had this functionality for a long time. :)

Some examples/how-to's:

- [Create User Entry Forms In Word 2010](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/create-user-entry-forms-in-word-2010/)
- [Creating Simple Forms in MS Word 2007 with Protection Restrictions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6bUE0Y6LxU)

[OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/) will also let you create fillable forms, and additionally save them to PDF:

- [How-to: Create PDF forms with OpenOffice](http://danilop.wordpress.com/2008/07/02/how-to-create-pdf-forms-with-openoffice/)

Comment: I mentioned that I had tried word forms, so I'm looking for something other than MS Office, preferably that saves PDF with the information filled out.

Answer (score 0):

I've been a LaTeX user for years, so this answer might be biased, but there are ways to make input boxes inside documents with LaTeX.

This particular feature was even [discussed on Stackoverflow](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html). It is part of the [`hyperref` package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944863/pdf-forms-with-latex-how-to-create-textfield-of-exactly-4in-width).

The best documents I've ever seen were typeset with LaTeX, so even if it takes quite some work to get things done in the first place, the result is excellent.